# Substring replace

Tags: c, string

I want to implement a c code such that it replaces only the exact matching not part of another string.
check out my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ()
{
   char str[] ="This is a simpled simple string";
   char * pch;
   char str1[]= "simple";
   pch = strstr (str,str1);
   strncpy (pch,"sample",6);
   puts (str);
   return 0;
 }
```

the above code gives the output : This is sampled simple string

I want the output to be : This is simpled sample string

please help

Thanks.

Comment: Repeat the search and replace.

Comment: "exact matching not part of another string" - the *word* you're looking for is **word**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to deal with these types of question is consider **each and every** word *one-by-one*. And then check whether, the `pattern` *(which we are looking for?)* is present in the given string or not, if yes then replace it with replacing `word`.

Below is my code. *(I know it may seem bit odd one out, but trust me it will work for any pattern-matching and replacement problem)*. It will **reduce** and **expand** the final output according to the given `pattern` word and its corresponding `replacement` word.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    /*    This program will replace the "demo" with "program"    */
    char input[] = "   isdemo Hello this is demo. replace demo with demoes something else demo";
    char pattern[] = "demo";
    char replace[] = "program";
    char output[105];
    int index = 0;

    /*Read the the input line word-by-word, 
      if the word == pattern[], then replace it else do nothing */
      for(int i=0; i<strlen(input);) {
          while(i<strlen(input) && !isalpha(input[i])) {
              output[index++] = input[i++];
          }

          char temp[105]; int j = 0;
          while(i<strlen(input) && isalpha(input[i])) {
              temp[j++] = input[i++];
          } 
          temp[j] = 0;

          if(strcmp(temp, pattern) == 0) {
             strncpy(output+index, replace, strlen(replace));
             index += strlen(replace);
          } else {
             strncpy(output+index, temp, strlen(temp));
             index += strlen(temp);
          }
      }

      output[index] = 0;
      puts(output);

    return 0;
}
```

If i'm still missing any test case. I will be pleased to know about it.

Comment: You don't check the beginning of the string. Thus, the code will also transform `issimple` to `issample`.

Comment: @user0815. Now check the edit and let me know if any test case is still pending.

Answer (score 0):

A word can start with space or may lie at the start of string and can end with a space, a full stop, a comma or with the end of string. using these conditions you can easily identify any word within a string. Following code describes it according to your example.

**Using this code you can replace a word with another word of any size.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char str[] = "simple This is a simpled simple simple. simple, string simple";
    char * pch;
    char * result = str;
    char * temp;

    char str1[] = "simple"; //string to be replaced
    char str2[] = "sample"; //string to be replaced with

    pch = strstr(result, str1);
    while(pch)
    {
        temp = result;
        if ((pch == str || *(pch - 1) == ' ') && (strlen(pch) == strlen(str1) || !isalpha(*(pch + strlen(str1)))))
        {
            result = (char*)malloc(strlen(temp)+(strlen(str2) - strlen(str1))+1); //allocate new memory, +1 for trailing null character
            strncpy(result, temp, pch - temp); // copy previous string till found word to new allocated memory
            strncpy(result + (pch - temp), str2, strlen(str2)); // replace previous word with new word
            strncpy(result + (pch - temp) + strlen(str2), pch + strlen(str1), strlen(pch + strlen(str1))); // place previous string after replaced word
            strncpy(result + strlen(temp) + (strlen(str2) - strlen(str1)), "\0", 1); // place null character at the end of string
            if (temp != str)
                free(temp); // free extra memory
        }
        pch = strstr(result + (pch - temp) + 1, str1); // search for another word in new string after the last word was replaced
    }

    puts(result);
    if (result != str)
        free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about `single` at the end or at the beginning of a string? Does also not replace multiple occurrences.

Comment: Much better now. I like how the edge cases are detected. You may consider using `isalpha` instead of testing against multiple non-characters.

Comment: @user0815 Now strings of two different sizes can be replaced with each other.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need search the entire string continuously until no substring is found, second, you need check the char before and after the substring returned by strstr, to make sure that the found substring is a complete word. When check for word boundary, take special care when the word is at the beginning or end of the longer string. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char str[] ="simple simples is a simpled simple string simple";
    char *s = str;
    char *pch = str;
    char str1[]= "simple";
    int len = strlen(str1);
    int pos;
    while (1) {
        pch = strstr(s, str1);
        if (!pch)  // no more occurrences of str1, quit
            break;
        pos = pch - str;
        if (pos == 0) { // if it's the beginning
            if (!isalpha(pch[len])) {
                strncpy(pch, "sample", 6);
            }
        } else { // check two ends
            if (!isalpha(*(pch-1)) && !isalpha(*(pch+len))) {
                    strncpy(pch, "sample", 6);
            }
        }
        s = pch + len;
   }
   puts(str);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good approach. However, it will not work if the strings differ in size.

Comment: No, it won't work if the string to replace is not the same size as the search string. He can make a copy of the original string and work on that. This is the simple approach to show him the problem.

Comment: @user0815: No-one has asked to replace strings that differ in size. You are raising a question that hasn't been asked and that has even prompted a long answer that fails to address the actual problem, namely how to find whole words.

Comment: @MOehm I disagree. Strings in general can differ in size and that is even more likely. Instead the OP should have stated that both strings are guaranteed to have the same size. That is, you make assumptions that aren't given.

Comment: There isn't a lot to assume, really. The example in the question is a very small, closed piece of code whose purpose is to highlight the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my code.This deals with the replacement that you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void replace(char *buf, size_t bufSize, const char *word_to_replace, const char *replacement_word);

int main(void)
{
    char str[100] = "simple Asimple simpleB This is a simpled simple string and simple is good sometimes!, simple";
    replace(str, sizeof(str), "simple", "sample");
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}

void replace(char *buf, size_t bufSize, const char *word_to_replace, const char *replacement_word)
{
    size_t buf_len = strlen(buf), word_len = strlen(word_to_replace);
    char *ptr = strstr(buf, word_to_replace);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find matches.\n");
        return;
    }
    bool _G = 0;
    char *tmp = (char *)malloc(bufSize);

    // Deal with begining of line
    if (ptr == buf) {
        if (ptr[word_len] == ' ' || ptr[word_len] == '\0') {
            _G = 1;
        }
        if (_G) {
            strcpy_s(tmp, bufSize, ptr + word_len);
            *ptr = 0;
            strcat_s(buf, bufSize, replacement_word);
            strcat_s(buf, bufSize, tmp);
            _G = 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (*(ptr - 1) == ' ' && (ptr[word_len] == ' ' || ptr[word_len] == '\0')) {
            _G = 1;
        }
        if (_G) {
            strcpy_s(tmp, bufSize, ptr + word_len);
            *ptr = 0;
            strcat_s(buf, bufSize, replacement_word);
            strcat_s(buf, bufSize, tmp);
            _G = 0;
        }
    }
    // deal with the rest
    while (ptr = strstr(ptr + 1, word_to_replace))
    {
        if (*(ptr - 1) == ' ' && (ptr[word_len] == ' ' || ptr[word_len] == '\0')) {
            _G = 1;
        }
        if (_G) {
            strcpy_s(tmp, bufSize, ptr + word_len);
            *ptr = 0;
            strcat_s(buf, bufSize, replacement_word);
            strcat_s(buf, bufSize, tmp);
            _G = 0;
        }
    }
    free(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Does also transform `issimple` into `issample` and is not safe against buffer overflows. It also won't work if `simple` is at the end of the string.

Comment: That's all well and good, but is doesn't answer the OP's question, which is how to find whole words. Your answer shows how to replace a single occurrence with a string of arbitrary length.

Comment: I would suggest `puts("This is a simpled sample string")` to solve the OP's example. Additional functionality can be added based on that.